# jQuery - Change background colour on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I want to transition the background colour of a fixed header element on scroll. So as a user scrolls down a full page block website, the header subtly changes to complement the block colours. I have almost achieved this on a [Pen](http://codepen.io/ajm90UK/pen/oYyerB), however I can't quite work out how to measure how much has been scrolled as a flag for when to change.

**Some extra info:** The scroll amount to change at is 400px. The background colours are stored and fetched in an array. For reference my jQuery code is below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var bgArray = ["#252525","#333333","#454545","#777777"];  
  var scrollHeight = 400;
  var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop(); //What is this measuring?

  $(window).scroll(function() { //Can these conditions be neatened into one function?
    if(scrolled < scrollHeight) {
      $('header').css('background', bgArray[0]);
    }
    if(scrolled > scrollHeight) { // i.e more than 400px
      $('header').css('background', bgArray[1]);
    }
    // and so on (800, 1200...)
  })
})
```

Please refer to the Pen for full code. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Some browsers trigger the scroll event for every scrolled pixel, draining performance. Debouncing will help with that: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Comment: Thanks for this, where should I add $.debounce in relation to the answer below?

Comment: `$( window ).on('scroll', $.throttle( 250, function(){ /* Code goes here */ }) );`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Updated Solution (2019)

To set a `background` for the `header` based on the current *block* in view below the `header` while scrolling:

- because `header` has *fixed position*, we can get *the amount by which window has scrolled* by using `$header.offset().top`,
- (*index of the current block in view*) is the ratio of (*the amount by which window has scrolled*) to the (*height of each block*),
- now adjusting for the height of the `header`, the index of the current block in view is `Math.floor(($header.offset().top + headerHeight) / sectionHeight)`.

See simplified demo below:

```js
$(function() {
  var $header = $('header'),
    $window = $(window),
    bgArray = ["#252525", "red", "blue", "green"],
    headerHeight = 50,
    sectionHeight = 400;

  $window.scroll(function() {
    $header.css('background', bgArray[Math.floor(($header.offset().top + headerHeight)
        / sectionHeight)]);
  });
});
```

```css
:root {
  --header: 50px; /* header height */
  --block: 400px; /* block height */
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* include padding in width / height calculations */
}

body {
  margin: 0; /* reset default margin of body */
}

header {
  height: var(--header); /* sets height of header */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 12px 0;
  background: #252525; /* initial background */
  transition: background 1s ease;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrap>div {
  height: var(--block); /* sets height of each block */
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  margin: 0; /* reset margin of p */
}

.block-1 {
  background: #27AACC;
  color: #FFF;
}

.block-2 {
  background: #668E99;
  color: #FFF;
}

.block-3 {
  background: #4AFFC1;
  color: #444;
}

.block-4 {
  background: #FF8F8A;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="container">
    Website Title.
  </div>
</header>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="block-1">
    <div class="container">
      <p>This pen was made to solve a problem on a project...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block-2">
    <div class="container">
      <p>...I needed a sticky header with thr right bg colour.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block-3">
    <div class="container">
      <p>But this conflicted with the footer, which was the same colour...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block-4">
    <div class="container">
      <p>So the solution was to subtley change the header's bg on scroll</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

## **Original Solution**

Check the `top` of each `block` with respect to how much the window has been scrolled (`scrollTop`) using `$(window).scrollTop() > $('.block-1').offset().top`. So now we can use this to change color on entering the block - see demo below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $header = $('header'),
    $window = $(window),
    bgArray = ["#252525", "#333333", "#454545", "#777777"],
    headerHeight = $header.outerHeight();

  $window.scroll(function() {
    for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
      if ($window.scrollTop() + headerHeight > $('.block-' + i).offset().top) {
        $header.css('background', bgArray[i - 1]);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700');
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 12px 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #252525;
  transition: background 1s ease;
}

.wrap {
  padding-top: 74px;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block-1,
.block-2,
.block-3,
.block-4 {
  height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  margin-top: 185px;
}

.block-1 {
  background: #27AACC;
  color: #FFF;
}

.block-2 {
  background: #668E99;
  color: #FFF;
}

.block-3 {
  background: #4AFFC1;
  color: #444;
}

.block-4 {
  background: #FF8F8A;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="container">
    Website Title.
  </div>
</header>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="block-1">
    <div class="container">
      <p>This pen was made to solve a problem on a project...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block-2">
    <div class="container">
      <p>...I needed a sticky header with thr right bg colour.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block-3">
    <div class="container">
      <p>But this conflicted with the footer, which was the same colour...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block-4">
    <div class="container">
      <p>So the solution was to subtley change the header's bg on scroll</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that this solution needlessly *loops* through the sections on each scroll update called by the browser - and I don't like the look of it.

Comment: why the `for` loop?

Comment: The loop neatens things up nicely, and this solutions makes most sense to me! Thanks very much

Comment: Is there a way to take into account the height of the Header, so it effectively changes 50px before the offset height?

Comment: You want to break browsers? Because this is how you break browsers. I'm going to fix a little

Comment: That's why I said that it can be optimized in a comment above :)

Comment: Saved some references. This will still be a performance killer in FF, which fires the scroll event EVERY PIXEL. I highly recommend http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Comment: and you're right - *debouncing* is highly recommended for performance...

Comment: If you scroll back to top too quickly, the background won't change because of the debounce delay. I'll add an extra line that always check the top margin and sets the bg based on that as a failsafe

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on chrome for android nougat.

Comment: updated answer with a newer solution, thanks all :)

Answer (score 7):

you are using scrolled as a fixed variable you should use it directly in your condition

this will make it dynamic for all elements inside wrap div

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var bgArray = ["#252525","#333333","#454545","#777777"];
$(window).scroll(function() { 
    for(var i = 1; i < bgArray.length; i++) {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('.wrap div:nth-child(' + i + ')').offset().top) {
        $('header').css('background', bgArray[i-1]);        
      }
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: This is great and explains it well +!, however only seems to deal with the first 2 items in array?

Comment: What about when page is scrolled to `800px`, `1200px`... ?

Comment: One note - to prevent unnecessary browser repaints, you could add a condition that checks if the header is already the color you're about to set it to.

Answer (score 4):

Try Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var bgArray = ["#252525","#333333","#454545","#777777"];  
  var scrollHeight = 400;

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop(); 

    var index=Number((scrolled/scrollHeight).toFixed());

    if(bgArray[index]!=undefined)
        $('header').css('background', bgArray[index]);

  });
})
```

This is current scroll, so it should be inside:  `$(window).scrollTop()`

Comment: use of `modulo (%)` may be flawed here, as `425%400` will return `25` but max index is `3`.