# Change element color black or white depending on background color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm setting up a new website, and I want to change logo color (that is `position: fixed`) depending on background color or image.

An example that I found is on [this site](https://wepresent.wetransfer.com/story/breaking-the-circle-tobias-nathan/). You can look at how the logo and some elements change color depending on background.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.logo img {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
}

.black {
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.imageBg {
  background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/2208895/pexels-photo-2208895.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260);
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/n/y/a/M/G/h/fdl-logo.svg">
</div>

<!-- change logo color to: black -->
<section class="yellow"></section>

<!-- change logo color to: white -->
<section class="black"></section>

<!-- change logo color to: white -->
<section class="red"></section>

<!-- change logo color to: black -->
<section class="yellow"></section>

<!-- change logo color to: white -->
<section class="imageBg"></section>
```

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o0gnayht/

Comment: possible guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41041176

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49494243/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/51630670/8620333

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by using `filter:invert()` you can change the logo color from black to white. If you use jquery in `onscroll` event you can call `filter` based on closest to top `section`

```js
$(window).scroll(function ()
{
 var windowTop = Math.max($('body').scrollTop(), $('html').scrollTop());
 $('section').each(function (index)
 {
  if (windowTop > ($(this).position().top - 100))
  {
   if ($(this).hasClass('yellow'))
   {
    $('.logo img').css('filter', 'invert(0)');
   }
   else
   {
    $('.logo img').css('filter', 'invert(1)');
   }
  }
 });
}).scroll();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.logo img {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
}

.black {
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.imageBg {
  background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/2208895/pexels-photo-2208895.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260);
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="logo">
  <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/n/y/a/M/G/h/fdl-logo.svg">
</div>

<!-- change logo color to: black -->
<section class="yellow"></section>

<!-- change logo color to: white -->
<section class="black"></section>

<!-- change logo color to: white -->
<section class="red"></section>

<!-- change logo color to: black -->
<section class="yellow"></section>

<!-- change logo color to: white -->
<section class="imageBg"></section>
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't change the colour of the logo, but I've made a basic function to determine whether it's dark:

```
<script>
  var data = [false, true, true, false, true];

  function isDark() {
    var scrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    var n = Math.floor((scrollPos + 50) / 400);
    console.log(data[n]);
    return data[n];
  }
</script>
```

When the user scrolls, the scroll position `window.pageYOfset` is used to determine which section the logo is above. It then uses the array `data` to determine what colour the logo should be.

The function will return true or false depending on what section the user has scrolled to.
To actually change the logo, you could replace it with an another image, or change the images colour using code behind.
Hope this helps.